# Rails routing issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Within a rails app I've got a special url (/profile) that I'm mapping to the user controller to allow a user to view and edit their profile.   I made the following entries into my route file so that the "get" for profile will route me to the profile action in the user controller and the "post" for profile will route to the update_profile action in the user controller.

```
match '/profile', :to => 'users#profile', :via => "get"
match '/profile', :to => 'users#update_profile', :via => "post"
```

If I run rake routes I see the following two entries

```
profile GET   /profile(.:format)  {:controller=>"users", ":action=>"profile"}
profile POST  /profile(.:format)  {:controller=>"users", ":action=>"update_profile"}
```

If I try hitting the dev url http://localhost:3000/profile it brings up the profile page as expected.  If I press the form button it gives me the following error:

```
Routing Error

No route matches "/profile"
```

Looking at the generated html on the initial page I see the following form tag, so it seems the action is correctly set.

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/profile" class="edit_user" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="edit_user_1" method="post">
```

So what am I missing?  By looking at the rake routes output, I was assuming this would work as is.  Am I thinking about my http verbs incorrectly?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few problems here.

First, these are actions for a specific user. So the route should probably be `'profile/:id'`

Secondly, show and update are automatically generated when you scaffold a resource. What is the benefit of renaming the actions and mapping them to custom URLs? Breaking the auto-generated Rails RESTful routes is often asking for trouble. It can be done, but you should have a good reason for doing it.

Third, your routes look funny to me. There are some quotes where they shouldn't be. Is that how they appear in your console when you run rake routes?

Comment: The concept of the /profile is that is only good for the current user, if you are not logged into the system, you will not be allowed to access the page, so no need for the :id in this case. We are using the generated urls for the user controller for admin capabilities which are a different user experience than what we want a user to have for their own profile.  So the edit action is used by a sys admin to edit an existing user where the profile action is to provide a different experience that is customized to the currently logged in user.  Yes, that is how it appears in the console.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense. In that case, the only thing that looks funny to me is the actual routes. There should not be a quote before :action, wouldn't you agree? The only thing I can think of to try is to consistently use double quotes. In your routes you have single quotes around some strings and double quotes around others. It shouldn't make a difference, but it's worth a try.